# How to use DATE and DATE_FORMAT in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am fetching data using conditions based on dates from two tables using join. I am not able to create the query perfectly, it does not fetch data according to condition. The date saved in database is in the Y-m-d H:i:s format. The condition is that the 'created_at' should be greater than 'ts_lastNewHos' in the tables. created_at is in the viewers table and ts_lastNewHos is in the users table. When I see the query by sql_dump, ts_lastNewHos is blank. The data is available in table for such conditions. What might be the error.  The query is as below:

```
$this->paginate = array(
        'joins' => array(
                array(
                'table' => 'Users',
                'alias' => 'User',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Viewer.id = User.hosp_id',
                    'DATE(DATE_FORMAT("Y-m-d H:i:s",`created_at`)) >'=>DATE(DATE_FORMAT("Y-m-d H:i:s",ts_lastNewHos))  
                )
            )
        ),
        'fields' => array('Viewer.id','Viewer.name','Viewer.address1','Viewer.state','Viewer.district','Viewer.pin_code'),
        'limit' => 10,
        'conditions'=>array('DATE(DATE_FORMAT("Y-m-d H:i:s",`Viewer`.`created_at`)) >'=>DATE(DATE_FORMAT("Y-m-d H:i:s",`Users`.`ts_lastNewHos`)))); 

        $Datas = $this->paginate('Viewer');
        $this->set('Datas', $Datas);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select `viewers` based on the date equation, and join in `users` on the same conditon, then you should use an `INNER` join instead of using duplicate conditions.

Also there is no point using `DATE` *and* `DATE_FORMAT`, you only need one of them, and since you are saying that the values in the database are stored in `DATETIME` format, all you need should be `DATE()` in case you want to compare by only the date part.

And finally, you cannot put raw SQL in the `value` part of a `key => value` entry, as this will cause it to be escaped, and treated as a string in the resulting comparison. Instead, pass the SQL as a simple array value, just like you are already doing it for the primary/foreign key condition.

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'Users',
            'alias' => 'User',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Viewer.id = User.hosp_id',
                'DATE(`Viewer`.`created_at`) > DATE(`Users`.`ts_lastNewHos`)'
            )
        )
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        'Viewer.id',
        'Viewer.name',
        'Viewer.address1',
        'Viewer.state',
        'Viewer.district',
        'Viewer.pin_code'
    ),
    'limit' => 10
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.